# Joomla 2.5 get menu children

Tags: menu, joomla2.5, submenu

I have been searching for this and didn't find anything.
I know how to get the parent menu name and the active page, but couldn't find how could I get the **NOT** active children.

This is what I have:

```
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$activeChild = $active->title;
$parentId = $active->tree[0];
$parentName = $menu->getItem($parentId)->title;
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
echo "<hr>";
echo $parentName . " > " . $activeChild;
```

Example menu:

`- Menu
-- Sub1
-- Sub2
-- Sub3`

If we are in `Sub2` page the output is:
`Menu > Sub2`

But how can I output the other children too? In their native order?

Comment: Hi! Why not to ask Joomla-related questions directly at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) in the future?

Comment: @miroxlav I did, but no one answered...

Comment: Few days ago I tried to compare number of unanswered question here and there. I found out that Joomla gurus are now concentrated at joomla SE and here at [so] is chance of answering somewhat lower. Hence my recommendation. But I'm glad that you got the answer. Please don't forget to accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting that you want to get all children of active parent.If yes,You can try below code -

```
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$activeChild = $active->title;
$parentId = $active->tree[0];
$parentName = $menu->getItem($parentId)->title;
$childs = $menu->getItems( 'parent_id', $parentId);
echo '<pre>';print_r($childs);echo '</pre>';
```